How do I save the email address I received from the Kivymd interface in the Django model?
My goal is to save the data I receive from the Kivymd interface in the Django model. Actually, there is no problem in saving many types of data, but the e-mail part caused problems.
Below, I have shown the Django models and the operations on the Kivymd side (1. Getting the data from the front; 2. Post processing with DRF).
from django.db import models

class Model(models.Model):
   user_mail = Model.EmailField()

And the posting progress
...
def data(self): 
email = self.screen.ids.email_id.text
requests.post(url, json('user_mail':'email')

This is in its simplest form, I can give details if you want... And it returns a request 400 error as output:
"POST /users// HTTP/1.1" 400 37

It is worth noting that I received the entered address, but as you can see, an error occurs in the sending part.

EmailField should be defined using models.EmailField(). Write     user_mail = models.EmailField()

The HTTP 400 Bad Request client error response status code indicates that the server would not process the request due to something the server considered to be a client error., i think there is problem in your urls or endpoints also the output says "POST /users// HTTP/1.1" 400 37 and users// have // this is not valid pls add your urls to your question

pls read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Can you show other model fields that worked ?
